# How to draw curved arrows in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, shapes, affinity-designer, arrow

I'm trying to draw these arrows in Photoshop. They were originally done in Affinity Designer. I couldn't find equivalent tool to draw these paths/arrows.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Affinity Designer is a vector image editor. Photoshop isn't. Use  a vector image editor instead such as Illustrator, Inskcape, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, Photoshop can only add arrowheads to straight lines, made using the `Line` tool. The `Path` tool seems to not have an arrowheads option.

[image]

However, Illustrator can do this more easily and gives extra control to styling paths and arrowheads.

[image]